# Finding indices of numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy.ndarray (data) that has 5 elements and each element has 2042 rows and two columns. The first column contains dates (on 15-minute intervals) and the second contains temperatures. I am working a script that will find the max temperature in a 24-hour period. I have a working script for that.

```
x1=0
y1=95
maxTblue=[] 

for i in range(int(len(data[0])/96)+1):
    #collect the max temp for 24-hr period
    maxTblue.append(max(data[0][x1:y1,1]))
    #add 96 to shift to the next 24-hr period
    x1+=96
    y1+=96
```

Now, I want to be able to collect the date where the max temperature occurs for each 24-hour period. I tried the following script but it's giving me the wrong dates. The dates should increase by 24-hour periods, but the current script is returning dates from the first 24-hour period.

```
maxdateBlue=[]
locblue=[]
x3=0
y3=95
for i in range(int(len(data[0])/96)+1):
    #index for the max temp 
    locblue.append(np.where(data[0][x3:y3,1]==maxTblue[i]))
    #date where the max temp occurs
    maxdateBlue.append(data[0][locblue[i],0])
    x3+=96
    y3+=96
```

How do I properly use np.where, or how do I use another indices command to find out when my max temperatures occur?

Answer (score 2):

To find the index of the maximum value in a numpy array use [np.argmax()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)